# The chart doesn't display the data from my call to the API with Axios

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, chart.js

I have been trying for some time to display a graph with data coming from my API with axios. The get with axios on the API worked well but the data is not displayed on the graph. However, I followed the tutorial with the v-if = loaded on chart.js.

Can anyone help me because i really don't understand ?

Thank you

Here is my code :

````
`<template>
  <div class="charts">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="flex md6 xs12">
        <va-card
          v-if ="loaded"
          class="chart-widget"
          :title="$t('charts.verticalBarChart')"
        >
          <va-chart :data="verticalBarChartData" type="vertical-bar"/>
        </va-card>
      </div>
      <div class="flex md6 xs12">
        <va-card
          class="chart-widget"
          :title="$t('charts.horizontalBarChart')"
        >
          <va-chart :data="horizontalBarChartData" type="horizontal-bar"/>
        </va-card>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="flex md12 xs12">
        <va-card
          class="chart-widget"
          :title="$t('charts.lineChart')"
        >
          <va-chart :data="lineChartData" type="line"/>
        </va-card>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="flex md6 xs12">
        <va-card
          class="chart-widget"
          :title="$t('charts.pieChart')"
        >
          <va-chart :data="pieChartData" type="pie"/>
        </va-card>
      </div>
      <div class="flex md6 xs12">
        <va-card
          class="chart-widget"
          :title="$t('charts.donutChart')"
        >
          <va-chart :data="donutChartData" type="donut"/>
        </va-card>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="flex md12 xs12">
        <va-card
          class="chart-widget"
          :title="$t('charts.bubbleChart')"
        >
          <va-chart :data="bubbleChartData" type="bubble"/>
        </va-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

```
<script>
var dataget
import { getLineChartData } from '../../../data/charts/LineChartData'
import { getBubbleChartData } from '../../../data/charts/BubbleChartData'
import { getPieChartData } from '../../../data/charts/PieChartData'
import { getDonutChartData } from '../../../data/charts/DonutChartData'
// import { getVerticalBarChartData } from '../../../data/charts/VerticalBarChartData'
import { getHorizontalBarChartData } from '../../../data/charts/HorizontalBarChartData'
import axios from 'axios'

```

```
export default {
  name: 'charts',
  data () {
    return {
      loaded : false,
      bubbleChartData: getBubbleChartData(this.$themes),
      lineChartData: getLineChartData(this.$themes),
      pieChartData: getPieChartData(this.$themes),
      donutChartData: getDonutChartData(this.$themes),
      verticalBarChartData: getVerticalBarChartData(this.$themes),
      horizontalBarChartData: getHorizontalBarChartData(this.$themes),
    }
  },
  methods: {
    refreshData () {
      this.lineChartData = getLineChartData(this.$themes)
    },
  },
  // Ajout
  async mounted () {
    this.loaded = false
    try {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8080/reading/_size?filter={"device":"Random-Integer-Device"}', {
        auth: {
          username: 'admin',
          password: 'secret'
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        //console.log(response.data._size);
        dataget = response.data._size;
        console.log("SIZE :  "+ dataget)
      })
      this.loaded = true

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  },
  // Ajout 
}

// this is a test 
const getVerticalBarChartData = (themes) => ({
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'USA',
      backgroundColor: themes.primary,
      borderColor: 'transparent',
      data: null, 
    },
    {
      label: 'USSR',
      backgroundColor: themes.info,
      borderColor: 'transparent',
      // It doesn't work here for dataget value
      data: [dataget, 10, 22, 39, 15, 20, 85, 32, 60, 50, 20, 30],
    },
  ],
})
// This is a test 
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.chart-widget {
  .va-card__body {
    height: 550px;
  }
}
</style>
```
````

Comment: Btw, console.log(dataget) display 76576

Comment: The problem is on verticalBarChartData

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `axios.get` makes an asynchronous HTTP request and assigns a value to the variable `dataget` only once it receives a response (inside the [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) function). The chart however is created when the variable `dataget` is still undefined.

Move the entire code block located between the two comments **// this is a test** to the [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) function just after the following code line and it should work.

```
dataget = response.data._size;
```